# Unable to generate a sitemap by Google's generator

Tags: google, sitemap

I would like to generate a sitemap by my Uni.s account such that I have a cron which continuously run the [sitemap_gen.py -file](http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/). The sitemap is for my site at Google Sites and particularly for the users of the site, not only for search engines.

**How can you generate a sitemap by Google's Python script in Google Sites which does not give access to the backend?**

Comment: is python supported by your development server?

Comment: I am making sitemaps for homepages made by Google sites, so I do not have an access to Python in the dev server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lol, as stukelly pointed out, you must run the python script directly on the server, not on your home computer

if your site is at google sites, i guess you don't have direct access to google servers (unless you are a really good hacker), so you can't run the python script

btw, i guess that google is already making a sitemap of their google sites

**edit**: otherwise, you could leech all your website with an "offline browser", and then try to get a sitemap from there

Comment: Google perhaps makes a sitemap. However, there seems to be no sitemap which user can see.

Comment: you have no way to get it automatically on the server
maybe you can leech all your website with an "offline browser", and then try to get a sitemap from there

Answer (score 1):

In short, it is impossible at the moment.

Comment: Do as Magnetic_dud suggested: Use HTTrack to download a copy of your site, run the script on that. Upload the generated file.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy if you'll provide URL list to the python script. So the answer is - by getting a list of URIs (which depends on your environment - do you have them in database, crawl for them, edit them manually, ...).

Comment: My sites are hosted by Google Sites. I do not have the URIs in database.